# How do I set the mime type in zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, xhtml, mime-types

I would like to set the repsonse mime type to

```
application/xhtml+xml
```

How and where do I set that in Zend Framework? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your controller action:

```
$this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/xhtml+xml');
```